# Comparing the value with negative number in Datatable in js

Tags: javascript

Im calculating a devaition between two values. If the deviation is up to -2 is accepted. If more than -2, like -2.5 or -3,it show red in color. So i used below code to check in datatable params. But the code itself didnt take the '-' in consideration. I tried to assign these limit one varaible and compare this new varaible with deviation value.But either way it is not working.

```
var dataTableParams = {

        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
               // Change the color of row when Deviation is more than -2 hrs
               if(serverData[1][4] =='Deviation')
               {
                   if ( aData[4] >= -2.0 )
                   {
                      $(nRow).css('color', 'red')
                   }
               }
            },              

        "aaData": data,
        "aoColumns": headers,
        "bSort": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 15,
        "iDisplayStart": 0
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "more" than -2 (-2.5 etc...). It means LESS than -2 ;)

Does it work if you use maths and you do something like that ?

```js
if ( aData[4] + 2.0 < 0)
{
  $(nRow).css('color', 'red')
}
```

Let me know ;)

Romain

Comment: Yes it should be less than(<) . Ur code works. Im new to Javascript,PHP. i wonder we cannot assign negative values to variable.

Comment: You can... For example try to create two variables (a & b fro example) with negatives values. Then console.log(a + b). It should work ;)